# Server-Client what is wrong here?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

So this is the first Server-Client I am trying to 'setup' but it does not work as I want it to. Here is What I want:

The Client to do:   (see comments in the code for the Client)

1. A 'user input' should be read by the Client
2. Send the 'user input' to the server
3. receive back something from the server

The server to do:  (See the comments in the code for Server)

1. receive the 'user input' that read by the client
2. Do something with the 'user input'
3. Send what was done in (2), back to the client.

It is not working the only right thing it is doing is that it receives the input from the 'user', that is it:

```
public class Cli {

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    Socket s; 
    public Cli(int port){
        try {
            s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                    (s.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.print("fel");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("fel");
        }
    } 

    public void startaClient(){
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            while(true){
                String userInput = stdIn.readLine();// get the user input (1)
                System.out.print("from user: " + userInput);
                out.write(userInput); // sends to server (2)
                System.out.println(in.readLine()); // receive from server(3)
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("fel1");
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Cli c=new Cli(4002);
        c.startaClient();
    }
```

Here is the code for the Server:

```
public class Ser {
    ServerSocket s;

    public Ser()throws  Exception{
        s = new ServerSocket(4002);
    }

    public void startaServern()throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = s.accept(); //waits for new clients, acceptera inkommande förfrågan
            Trad t = new Trad(socket);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        Ser b = new Ser();
        b.startaServern();
    }
}

public class Trad extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;

    public Trad(Socket s){
        socket=s;
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); // 
            out=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true); 
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("fel");}
    }


    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try{
                String theInput  = in.readLine(); //read, receive message from client (1)
                String res  =  theInput+"blabla";    // do something with the message from the client (2)
                out.write(res); // send it back to the client (3)

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("fel1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `readLine()` it will read a line i.e. until it reaches a new line.

Unless you send a new line it will wait forever.  I suggest you send a newline so the reader knows the line has ended.

Since you are using a `PrintWriter`  the simplest solution is to use

```
out.println(res);
```

instead of `out.write(res);`

Comment: the user should send a line of text to the client

Comment: Still you can send a line of text to the client with "out.println(res)" as suggested by Peter Lawrey

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it at first.  You mean that when the Server will send back to the client if I use: out.write(res) then it will not send the line but only write to the output stream.Instead the out.println(res) will write to the output stream and send it? @Ravindrababu , anyhow the problem is still present, nothing really happens

Comment: change to println at both server and client

Comment: @Ravindrababu   ok i did it and it seem to work .    but I still didn't really know what was different, out.write(res) vs out.println(res). Could u explain in short what was the difference

Comment: @user217273 println prints with a newline (thus println) whereas `write` just writes, nothing else like a newline.

Comment: @Ravindrababu , If I were to add a  line in the: run()  method such as System.out.println("recieved'), why isn't my server printing out :"received" infinitely many times? the while loop is always running

Comment: @user217273 your server is always waiting for the next line of input. It will only loop once per line of input.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks I still just don't get it . I mean I have an infinite loop which executes the  code in the run() method, how can it wait until the next line of input. I always thought nothing happened if there wasn't any input but the loop was still running and null was sent and received form server and client

Comment: @user217273 the loop doesn't busy wait, it only returns `null` when the connection is closed, in which case there is no point looping any more.